# WPF Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource and help using Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  



    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="DarkCyan">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>    
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=charList}" x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Pictures\bagi_warrior.jpg" Width="100" Height="150"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Character.Name}" FontSize="30"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=Character.Level}" FontSize="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Pictures\azure_knight.jpg" Width="100" Height="130"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Azure Knight"  FontSize="30"/>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Level 158"  FontSize="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label x:Name="strLabel" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" Content="Str: " HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="intLabel" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30" Content="Int: " HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="dexLabel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Content="Dex: " HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>
        <Label x:Name="goldLabel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Content="Gold: " HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"/>


    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Item}"></DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My XAML is such, it looks like this:

http://puu.sh/aLLrx.png

http://puu.sh/aLLsQ.jpg

my code is:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {

    Character aloken;
    Character azureKnight;
    Character bagiWarrior;
    Character incarMagician;
    Character segitaHunter;
    Character segnale;
    Character viciousSummoner;
    private List<Character> _charList = new List<Character>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        charList.Add(new Character("Bagi Warrior"));
        this.Item = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        this.Character = new ObservableCollection<Character>();

        this.DataContext = this;
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Bagi Warrior", level: 197, characterClass: CharacterClass.Bagi_Warrior, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 450, intelligence: 4, dexterity: 84, gold: 147203352));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Azure Knight", level: 158, characterClass: CharacterClass.Azure_Knight, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 390, intelligence: 120, dexterity: 92, gold: 204220567));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Incar Magician", level: 169, characterClass: CharacterClass.Incar_Magician, gender: Gender.Female, strength: 4, intelligence: 512, dexterity: 57, gold: 172223520));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Vicious Summoner", level: 203, characterClass: CharacterClass.Vicious_Summoner, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 423, intelligence: 89, dexterity: 45, gold: 114225587));

    }

    public List<Character> charList
    {
        get { return _charList; }
        set { _charList = value; }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Character> _Character;

    public ObservableCollection<Character> Character
    {
        get { return _Character; }
        set { _Character = value; }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Item> _Item;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Item
    {
        get { return _Item; }
        set { _Item = value; }
    }

}
```

Character Class (just in case):
http://pastebin.com/GFycKqDC

Item Class (just in case):
http://pastebin.com/RgXzbFHk

It's a project on a RPG where you have to use databinding for a combobox and to create an ObservableCollection for the combobox and view each Character.

The issue i'm running into is:
In my combobox, I want to be able to display the Character with their 'image' and next to it, their 'level' and 'name'

But I don't want it to be static, I want to create a list of Characters and bind the ItemsSource to my ComboBox so that no matter which character I select, information based on that character will update.
How do I do this?

I was told that creating a List of Characters, then make a data template for ComboBox Item that holds a pic, name, and level that are bound to selectedItem would do the job (which I did called charList) but whether I do it in code, or in XAML, it throws an exception saying that the collection must be empty before I bind to it.

I want to bind the properties in the datatemplate to selectedItem so that the labels and information will update appropriately.

What am I doing wrong, and why is this exception being thrown?

**EDIT**

Okay so now the problem is fixed! However, why does my Label binding still not work for Character.Name and Character.Level?

http://puu.sh/aLPr7.jpg

**EDIT 2**
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Character.Add(new Character("Bagi Warrior"));
            Character.Add(new Character("Azure Knight"));
            this.Item = new ObservableCollection();
            this.Character = new ObservableCollection();

```
        this.DataContext = this;
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Bagi Warrior", level: 197, characterClass: CharacterClass.Bagi_Warrior, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 450, intelligence: 4, dexterity: 84, gold: 147203352));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Azure Knight", level: 158, characterClass: CharacterClass.Azure_Knight, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 390, intelligence: 120, dexterity: 92, gold: 204220567));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Incar Magician", level: 169, characterClass: CharacterClass.Incar_Magician, gender: Gender.Female, strength: 4, intelligence: 512, dexterity: 57, gold: 172223520));
        //Character.Add(new Character(name: "Vicious Summoner", level: 203, characterClass: CharacterClass.Vicious_Summoner, gender: Gender.Male, strength: 423, intelligence: 89, dexterity: 45, gold: 114225587));

    }

    //public List<Character> charList
    //{
    //    get { return _charList; }
    //    set { _charList = value; }
    //}


    private ObservableCollection<Character> _Character;

    public ObservableCollection<Character> Character
    {
        get { return _Character; }
        set { _Character = value; }
    }
```

and then XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="DarkCyan">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Character}" x:Name="comboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Width="100" Height="150"/>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="6*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Character.Name}" FontSize="30"/>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Path=Character.Level}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Each ComboBoxItem has an instance of Character as it's DataContext so the correct path is Name and Level. It's looking for a property called Character that itself has a property Name. Not sure why you have a List<Character> and an ObservableCollection<Character>.

Comment: And please mark my answer if that is what fixed it.

Comment: Could I do the same thing with 'Character' that i'm doing with 'charList', will it work the same way?

Comment: You typically use the ObservableCollection as the type for any collection you are binding to as an ItemsSource because it will notify the binding when you add/remove from the collection whereas List will not.

Comment: Why does my new code throw an exception then? TargetInvocationException was Unhandled @LeeO.

Comment: Create a new question with the exception and only the section of code where the exception is occurring.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are defining the ItemsSource twice.

Once using

```
ItemsSource="{Binding charList}"
```

and then again with

```
<ComboBoxItem>
```

You will want to replace the `ComboBoxItem` element with `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` and create a `DataTemplate` for your `ComboxItem`. Then you'll want to either bind the `Image Source` to a property on the Character class or use a [ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to have it use the appropriate `DataTemplate` for the item.
If only the image source location is changing, you could also use a datatrigger bound to the property defining the character class.

Comment: <ComboBoxItem> doesn't have ItemsSource though, it only has a Binding Path to the content of the label? Does this count as defining it twice? Ohhh I understand, so if I get rid of it, it now shows the Object location "ItemControl.Character" instead of the Character. How else should I edit it to do what I want?

Comment: You are adding another ComboBoxItem to the ComboBox with that code. Just like <TextBox>TEXT THAT WILL DISPLAY</Text> applies the text to the TextBox. <ComboBox><ComboBoxItem .....></ComboBox> will add that ComboBoxItem to the ItemsSource.

Comment: What you really wanted to do was define templates to use for the ComboBoxItems. You are going to have to use a ItemTemplateSelector to allow for different Templates unless you make Character a base class and then have the different character types as subclasses. Then you could create DataTemplates for the different items based on their data type.